# How to create an enum-style tree in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Say that I have a few hundred different items that needs to be sorted in a tree, like for example some representation of a folder structure.

```
           a1
          / | \
        a2 b2 c2
       / |  |
     a3 b3  c3
```

These items will also be defined statically in the code as each one has to be described manually.

Now say that I will mostly be accessing these items by it's path in the tree. I don't want to implement it with string identification because I wish to avoid problems caused by simple typos in my code (because an IDE won't help out with typos of structure inside strings). For example like this:

```
//Any typo inside the Strings would be ignored by the IDE.
Item item = tree.getChild("a1").getChild("a2").getChild("b3");
```

Or:

```
Item item = tree.get("a1\\a2\\b3");
```

My tree structure becomes more robust if I can simply do something like:

```
Item item = tree.a1.a2.b3;
```

I could accomplish this by implementing a class for every single item, however this sounds like overkill. There has to be a simpler way?

If I was doing this with just a one dimentional list, I could use enums to achieve what I want:

```
public enum Item {
    A1(1, "Description1"),
    A2(2, "Description2"),
    A3(3, "Description3");

    int prop1;
    String prop2;
    Item(int prop1, String prop2) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
}

Item item = Item.A3;
```

So it would be nice if there exists an enum-like structure for trees. I tried out hiarchical enums however the path to an item in such a structure doesn't seem to be locked. I can access a low level item just by it's name without the rest of it's path.

Comment: What's wrong with a proper class instead of an enum? All you need are two classes `Tree` and `Child` and each `Child` can reference other `Child` classes

Comment: "Item item = tree.a1.a2.b3" is more of a compile time thing and I think that you want some thing that is more dynamic. right?

Comment: @cricket_007 *I could accomplish this by implementing a class for every single item, however this sounds like overkill. There has to be a simpler way?*

Comment: Do you need to access both `item.a1` and `item.a1.a2`? E.g., are all nodes in the tree potentially terminal? Or only some of them?

Comment: @JordiCastilla And I pointed out that a class for every single item isn't needed (at least I interpret that as class files, not class instances)

Comment: The dot-notation, e.g. `tree.a1.a2.b3`, is something done by the compiler for accessing named *fields*, so the only way to get that is a new class for every node in the tree. You could just make flat constants, e.g. `tree_a1_a2_b3`, but it's still very static. How do you expect any implementation for *"large number of different items"* to be compiler checked, without statically defining all the items? I'd say, go with the `getChild("a1")` style, and let your unit test catch any typos. You do have unit tests, right?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm aware. And this will be my solution if I can't find something else.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I do need to access every node, not just leaves.

Comment: @Andreas The use of the term "large number" might be misinterpreted. I will edit the original post to avoid confusion. Items will be added manually to the list one at a time because they are yet to be defined. The tree will not need to be dynamic, hence my comparison with enums. Yes if I am forced to use a normal tree I'll have to catch typos without the help of an IDE. I'm looking for an improvement so that I won't have to implement my own typo check.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing an enum element for each possible item is mad and isn't at all realistically maintainable or scalable. Why don't you just make a simple `Tree` class that mimics the structure of a tree, and that can store any data type desired?

```
public class Tree<T> implements ITree<T> {

    public final T value;
    private List<ITree<T>> children;

    public Tree(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void addChild(ITree<T> child) {
        if(this.children == null) this.children = new LinkedList<T>();
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    @Override
    public ITree<T> getChild(int i) {
        return children.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}

public class EmptyTree<T> implements ITree<T> {

    @Override
    public void addChild(ITree<T> child) {

    }

    @Override
    public ITree<T> getChild(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return null;
    }

}

interface ITree<T> {
    public void addChild(ITree<T> child);
    public ITree<T> getChild(int i);
    public T getValue();
    public boolean isEmpty();
}

ITree<String> tree = new Tree<String>("a1");
tree.addChild(new Tree<String>("a2"));
tree.addChild(new EmptyTree<String>());
String rootVal = tree.getValue(); // "a1"
String childVal = tree.getChild(0).getValue(); // "a2"
boolean child2Val = tree.getChild(1).isEmpty(); // true
```

As the children are stored in a list, it is of course unnecessary to implement the `EmptyTree` class, but this design could be easily adapted to the strict use of binary trees if need be by using the `EmptyTree` class.

Comment: `public class EmptyTree<T> : ITree<T>`: that's not valid Java code, I'm guessing it's C#. Please fix your code.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description, however I'm already familiar with this and it would be what I would do if I can't find any other solution. All items will be defined statically in the code, so there's no way around the maintainability mess that will come from this. If I alternatively move the list out of the code I'm still stuck maintaining it wherever it is.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Thanks for letting me know! I have been doing a lot more c# than Java lately.

Answer (score 0):

There is no satisfactory way of implementing this in Java.

One option would be to have a separate class for every item and referring to them by type, something like this:

```
Item item = tree.getChild(A1.class).getChild(A2.class).getChild(B3.class);
```

All of these classes could inherit from a common base class that implements the `getChild()` method.

While this is compile-time safe, it will also be a huge hassle implementing it. Using a DSL-friendly language like Scala or Groovy would make this a lot less painful.